# ASP.NET control in GridView not found to exist in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a DropDownList that I would like to populate with column values from a DataBase. However, when I try to bind the DropDownList in code behind, the IDE keeps telling me:

"The name 'EqpCatDDL' does not exist in the current context"

I am not sure what is going on since I referred to the control by its ID. The following is the code:

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="S/N" HeaderText="S/N" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="EqpCatDDL" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DescripDDL" runat="server">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

c#:

```
    public void Populate1()
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EqpCateID, EqpCat FROM EqpCategory", connection);
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader ddlValues;
    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    EqpCatDDL.DataSource = ddlValues;
    EqpCatDDL.DataValueField = "EqpCateID";
    EqpCatDDL.DataTextField = "EqpCat";
    EqpCatDDL.DataBind();

    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Connection.Dispose();
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Populate1(); 
}
```

The IDE can't find the EqpCatDDL control.

I am using the following: Visual Studio 2010, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008

I am working with a Visual Studio website

Comment: You can't bind a DropDownList in GridView like the above. For that, you need a loop to iterate and get it's index value.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to bound data to `dropdown` without using `RowDataBound`.

Create a function that'll bind the Data to `dropdown` as follow and call it in `Page_Load` event

```
Public void fill_gridView_dropDown()
{
    // your connection and query to retrieve dropdown data will go here 
    // this loop will go through all row in GridView
    foreach(GridViewRow row in your_gridView_Name.Rows) {
        DropDownList  dropDown = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("dropDownList_id");
        dropDown.DataSource = dataSource;
        dropDown.DataValueField = "ValueField";
        dropDown.DataTextField = "TextField";
        dropDown.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Please note that you have to `bind` GridView first, and then you have to bind your dropdown**

Answer (score 1):

your dropdown is in gridview so you can try with this code

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    var ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("EqpCatDDL'");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EqpCateID, EqpCat FROM EqpCategory", connection);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    EqpCatDDL.DataSource = ds;
    EqpCatDDL.DataValueField = "EqpCateID";
    EqpCatDDL.DataTextField = "EqpCat";
    EqpCatDDL.DataBind();

}
}
```

Comment: I would move the data base access to Page_load and have global variable to store the dataset. That way the database is only called once, not once per data row.

Comment: you can create global method for dataset which contains your result and method return type is DataSet. so you can apply as DDL.DataSource  = your metod name;

Comment: The problem with that is the method and therefore the database is accessed for everyrow. If there are 1000 rows that is 999 calls too many  to the database.

Comment: http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/196731/Unable-to-bind-DropDownList-when-new-row-is-added-dynamically-to-ASPNet-GridView/                just goto this link.It will be useful for you

Comment: Another alternative is to do it in `DataBound` instead of `RowDataBound`. You could access the database only once, and loop through the rows to fill the DropDownList in each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly populate `GridView's` `dropdownlist` like this. You need to set datasource of `GridView` first i.e.

```
GridView1.DataSource = DataSource
```

And if you would like to access `dropdownlist` of this gridview, you can use `RowDataBound` event handler of `GridView` i.e.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Checking whether the Row is Data Row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Finding the Dropdown control.
        Control ctrl = e.Row.FindControl("EqpCatDDL");
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            DropDownList dd = ctrl as DropDownList;
            List lst = new List();
            dd.DataSource = lst;
            dd.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```