# How do I bind values from gridview to popup inside dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code

```
con.Open();
ImageButton btndetails = sender as ImageButton;
GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;
BindRolesdropdown();
ddl.SelectedValue = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;

protected void BindRolesdropdown()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" select  distinct Rolename,RoleId from  Roles", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    ddl.DataTextField = "Rolename";
    ddl.DataValueField = "RoleId";
    ddl.DataSource = ds;
    ddl.DataBind();
    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0")); 
}
```

My 0<sup>th</sup> cell is the Image edit button. When I click that popup will show. But now the value not bind in the drop down list which is the gridview.

My sql table `Roles`

```
RoleName     RoleId                                 IsActive
Admin        324F5D29-4A8F-43F3-B060-1589F6BDBFC8   1
Team Leader  944C2E84-A648-4293-9D5A-EA58FB9727B6   1
```

If I select Admin row in the grid the popup inside the grid should show the admin the dropdown list. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are almost done, I guess. Does the above shows any error?

Comment: The value are not bind in the drop downlist It doesn't show any error

Comment: use INotifyPropertyChanged event and bind the value to the dropDownlist

Comment: I suggest you to get the DropDownList values in a List<> and finally bind them.

Comment: Visit this link, it might help you [Bind dropdownlist in GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360652/asp-net-control-in-gridview-not-found-to-exist-in-code-behind/39370409#39370409)

Comment: Before calling method `BindRolesdropdown();` save `gvrow.Cells[1].Text` in session/hidden field.Bind selected value after `ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));` inside definition `BindRolesdropdown()` .For Eg. ddl.SelectedValue = Session[] or HiddenField.value