# My Dropdown list Selected index changed isnt running

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So, i have a drop down list in a gridview as follows:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvPrevActionPlans" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="REC_ID" HeaderText="Record ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ACTIONPLAN" HeaderText="Action Plan" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="REQDATE" HeaderText="Target Date" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Progress">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddAPUpdate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddAPUpdate_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem>In Progress</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Deadline Not Met</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Completed</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The c# if you're curious:

```
protected void ddAPUpdate_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack) return;
        if (gvPrevActionPlans.Rows.Count == 0) return;
        for (var i = 0; i < gvPrevActionPlans.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var ddStatus = (DropDownList)gvPrevActionPlans.Rows[i].FindControl("ddAPUpdate");
            var constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DATABASENAMEHERE(kept out for security reasons)"].ConnectionString;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                try
                {
                    var cmd =
                        new SqlCommand(
                            "SqlQueryHere")
                        {
                            CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                            Connection = con
                        };


                    //Parameters added Here


                    con.Open();
                    if (ddStatus.SelectedItem.ToString() != "In Progress")
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    string errorMsg = "Error in Insert";
                    errorMsg += ex.Message;
                    throw new Exception(errorMsg);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Ive tried adding *AutoPostback = true* and *EnabledViewState = true* too, when i put a breakpoint on the eventhandler it never breaks, so im assuming that the dropdownlist doesnt actually trigger the event, no clue why though? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your page load event

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not wrap the databinding of the GridView in an `IsPostBack` check. If you didn't, it will set all the DropDowns back to their default on every page load and `SelectedIndexChanged` is not fired.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    gvPrevActionPlans.DataSource = source;
    gvPrevActionPlans.DataBind();
}
```

You will still need to add `AutoPostBack="true"` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddAPUpdate_SelectedIndexChanged"` to the DropDown.

**UPDATE**

And this line will cause the method to never continue executing, since it always is a PostBack. It will always be true and therefore always returns on the first line.

```
if (IsPostBack) return;
```

Test it yourself

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack) return;

    //the label will never change since a button click is a PostBack and immediately returned
    Label1.Text = "This is a test";
}
```

Comment: I've already added those before, they arent there at the moment because that didnt fix it (and i tried to use a button to force the changes but the ddl's still aren't having their values changed

Comment: Updated my answer, your method will not complete as it is now.

Comment: I'm not trying to retrieve data, i'm making an update to a database based on what a drop down lists value it, and i'm already doing what you're suggesting, `if(IsPostBack) return;` and `if(!IsPostBack)` are the same thing

Comment: Yes you are, otherwise you'll have an empty GridView. And `if (IsPostBack) return;` and `if (!IsPostBack)` are NOT the same thing.

Comment: No im not, the gridview is already populated, i have a dropdown list in the gridview which is supposed to change the database behind when the dropdown list selected index is changed.  Also, if i only have one if statement in my method, then writing `if(IsPostBack) return;` and `if(!IsPostBack)` are exactly the same, it just reduces the nesting required, when IsPostBack is true in both cases it will not run the rest of the code in that method, and when both false it will not run the code... i really don't see the difference here

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the event and AutoPostback (again) on the markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddAPUpdate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddAPUpdate_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try code from this link in your `dropdown` `selectedindexchanged` event

[fetch dropdownlist from gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39370409/3796419)

Comment: My problem isnt retrieving the data from the gridview.. It's that my event handler doesnt run, like the first line of C# doesnt even run on it